# After scrolling beyond the SE site's logo/name, replace the "StackExchange" sticky header logo with it

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, top-bar

It's very useful for the user to know which SE site they're using at a glance. For example, I use [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/273977/wis?tab=profile), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/20087/), [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), which can have very similar, if not the same, questions. Often I know exactly what I'm looking for/need, and I want to go back to an answer I remember reading before, to copy from it, but I don't remember which site it was on.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I agree with this. We get a lot of new users asking blatantly off-topic questions on this site, and many of those are because users get here from some link and don't realize that they've been directed to a different site. This will help in reducing said instances.

Comment: That is a pretty nifty user script. I think you should remove it and post it as an answer instead.

Comment: Yes, and also publish it on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). (cc @KodosJohnson)

Comment: @KodosJohnson and @ Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog took your advice and moved the userscript to an answer.

Comment: +1, I for one regularly click the "page logo" of web pages to get to the root page. Clicking the StackExchange logo is basically a lost click for me (and it requires another one to get out again).

Comment: if you disable the sticky header you don't have this problem ...

Comment: Less than an inch away is the URL on all major browsers (Including Internet Explorer!).  The URL is my "hack" to know what site I am on when using the internet.

Answer (score 11):

You can start using this today, or at least get a feel for this proposed change, while seeing if you agree with it, by using a userscript I made:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         "StackExchange" sticky header image to SE site's logo
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  change the sticky logo to the SE site's logo
// @author       Wis
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/**
// @match        https://*.askubuntu.com/**
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/**
// @match        https://*.serverfault.com/**
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
let sub = undefined;
const logo = document.querySelector("body > header.site-header > div > a > img");
if (logo === null) {
    sub = document.querySelector("body > header.site-header > div > a").cloneNode(true)
} else {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = logo.src;
    sub = img;
}
const stickyHeaderImg = document.querySelector("body > header.top-bar.js-top-bar.top-bar__network._fixed > div > div > a.-logo.js-gps-track.js-network-logo.network-logo");
const stackExchangeLogo = stickyHeaderImg.children[0];
const logo_size = logo.getBoundingClientRect();
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY > logo_size.height) {
        stickyHeaderImg.removeChild(stackExchangeLogo);
        stickyHeaderImg.prepend(sub);
    } else {
        stickyHeaderImg.removeChild(sub);
        stickyHeaderImg.prepend(stackExchangeLogo);
    }
});
```

It's [published on OpenUserJS](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/Wis/StackExchange_sticky_header_image_to_SE_sites_logo). You can install it by clicking the install button twice.

Demo:
[image: gif of “Stack Exchange” being replaced by “Meta” in the header]

Answer (score 6):

This is not something that we will be doing at this time. One of the reasons: many site logos will not look good on this type of background, and thus doing this will require lots of logo rework and/or custom styling per site.

Comment: Definitely agree; in the current form, it works for Meta because its logo is white, but it won't work for beta and non-designed sites (for example) because their logos are dark blue.